# Adding key to multiple arrays and filling the values for that key in order with the corresponding value from another ordered array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I have some code (below) that gets two arrays, a comma separated list of users that have claimed a product and a corresponding comma separated list of when they claimed it. It then matches the user_id to the users table and gets the user info in multiple arrays. I want to append the corresponding claimed_time into each of the outputted arrays, but can't figure out how to do it.

```
    $q = "SELECT claimed_by, claimed_time FROM post WHERE post_id='$post_id' AND accepted_user='' AND user_id='$id'";
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {
                $postrow = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $arr = explode(',', $postrow['claimed_by']);
                $arr2 = explode(',', $postrow['claimed_time']);

$users = array();
$r = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM users
WHERE id in (".implode(',',$arr).")");
$count=0;
 while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
    $multiple_row_result[] = $row;  
}


echo json_encode($multiple_row_result);//result
```

I've tried putting the following into the while loop with no success:

```
$multiple_row_result['claimed_time']=$arr2
```

I was thinking something along the lines of a foreach statement might work, but can't get anything to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to do this if you restructured your table structure.

But in your current format, you could do something like

```
while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){

    //get the key from the id array - $arr
    $key = array_search($row['id'], $arr);

   //get the claimed_time for the id using the $key and add to $row
   $row['claimed_time'] = $arr2[$key];

    $multiple_row_result[] = $row;  
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I've never used array_search before, but I'm glad I know it exists now. Will come in handy for sure. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. There are a lot of valuable built in function in php that you can use by searching the docs - ie. [`array_search()` - http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-search.php](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-search.php)